# React does not wait for server call to complete and throws error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rest, react-hooks

I have a working rest service that I want to invoke in react.

The code does display the list of countries.

```
import {React,  useEffect, useState } from 'react'

export const Noc = () => {

    const [nocs, setNoc] = useState();

    useEffect(
        () => {
            const fetchNoc = async () => {
                const response = await fetch('http://localhost:8080/countrydefinitions');
                const data = await response.json();
                setNoc(data);
                
            };
            fetchNoc();
        },[]
    );


    return <div>
     <div>NOC LIST</div>
     {nocs.map(noc => <div>{noc.region}</div>)}
      </div>
}
```

But most of the times I get this error

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined
```

**sometimes it prints the list soemetimes it does'nt. Is there some sort of a delay or wait that I need to introduce?**

How can I introduce a delay or make sure that setnoc has been called and nocs has a value before printing it.

Comment: Just give it a sane default value, i.e. an empty array in your case.

Comment: You only need to assign default value as array and the error wil gone. const [nocs, setNoc] = useState([]);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

React will rerender when the props change. Indeed at the beginning its nothing yet.

2 things to make it more solid can be done.

1. Add a default value, so that map is available on the array.

```js
const [nocs, setNoc] = useState([]);
```

2. And/Or wait until noc is not undefined anymore, and validating that It has a map function, before trying to use map.

```js
{nocs && typeof nocs.map === 'function' && nocs.map(noc => <div>{noc.region}</div>)}
```

Answer (score 1):

No. there is no need to introduce any delay/wait. That is already handled by the async/await syntax.

1. You can either set an initial value in your useState or early return a custom message if `nocs` is undefined.
2. If you are fetching from your own api, you can return a response with an error if the fetch request should fail. And then at client side, you can handle that error by wrapping your fetch call inside a try-catch block

```
import {useEffect, useState } from 'react'

export const Noc = () => {

    const [nocs, setNoc] = useState();

    useEffect(
        () => {
            const fetchNoc = async () => {
                const response = await fetch('http://localhost:8080/countrydefinitions');
                const data = await response.json();
                setNoc(data);
                
            };
            try{
                fetch()
            }catch(error){
                //handle error here
                console.log(error);
            }
        },[]
    );

    if(!nocs){
      return (<p>No NOC found</p>)
    }

    return <div>
     <div>NOC LIST</div>
     {nocs.map(noc => <div>{noc.region}</div>)}
      </div>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

at first render, `nocs` has no data then useEffect runs and the second render, `nocs` will have data.
you need to check if `nocs` is undefined
`{nocs && nocs.length > 0 && nocs.map(noc => <div>{noc.region}</div>)}`