# Employee.map is not a function

Tags: reactjs, axios

I have a component where am getting data using Axios HTTP request via companyId useParams react hook. The response is already mapped to show in `ListResults.js` and those results are used as props in `EmpDetailsList.js` to render data. In my data structure, I have an Array that holds multiple objects. My goal is to render the items from the objects to the user, for example. Company HIJ has two objects of employee details, and I want to list those details, specifically employee:

```
Company Name: HIJ
-Employee: Lesley Peden

-Employee: Wayne Smith
```

I have tried to map the result of employee in `EmpDetailsList.js` to show them, however, I get an error `employee.map is not a function`. Is this because I have already mapped the result in the previous component via Axios then response, preventing me to do it again? The only way I know of Listing these names is to map. Am I missing something?

Data Structure

```
 {
      company: "HIJ",
      address: "7890 street HIJ Road",
      _id: "610ae597597656758575",
      details: [
        {
          employee: "Lesley Peden",
          _id: "610ae55757579885595"
        },
        {
          employee: "Wayne Smith",
          _id: "610aeaec67575785858"
        }
      ],
      __v: 0
    }
  ]);
```

ListResults.js

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";
import axios from "axios";
import EmpDetailsList from "./EmpDetailsList";

const ListResults = () => {
  const [company, setCompany] = useState("");
  const [employee, setEmployee] = useState("");
  const { companyId } = useParams();

  useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get(`http://localhost:5000/url/${companyId}`)
      .then((res) => {
        setCompany(res.data.data.company);
        setEmployee(res.data.data.details.map((r) => r.employee));
      });
  }, [
    setCompany,
    setEmployee,
    companyId,
  ]);
  return (
    <>
          <h2>Company Name: {company} </h2>
          <EmpDetailsList employee={employee} />
    </>
  );
};
export default ListResults;
```

EmpDetailsList.js

```
const EmpDetailsList = ({ employee }) => {
      return (
            <Row>
              {employee.map((emp, id) => ( 
                  <h5 key={emp.id}>{emp}:</h5>
                 ))}   
            </Row>
      );
    };
    export default EmpDetailsList;
```

Comment: You need to check to see if `employee` is actually available `employee && employee.map ...` or initialise to an empty array

Comment: This got to be one of the most common questions

Comment: If you are getting `employee.map is not a function` then definitely `employee` is  not an array. In the `EmpDetailsList` try to `console.log(employee)` and see what is log on console.

Comment: are you sure that its `res.data.data.details` and not `res.data.details` ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React does not wait for server call to complete and throws error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68881355/react-does-not-wait-for-server-call-to-complete-and-throws-error)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### **Initialize your state with an empty array but not a string:**

```
const [employee, setEmployee] = useState([]);
```

You are doing right at the `setEmployee` in Axios fetch but the issue is laying on your initial render.

**Because in the initial render, `employee` is a string that you could not map through it.**

Comment: Thank you Ryan, such a simple answer, but effective!

Comment: Glad it helps you!